# I have a list of account names & ID's and I need to get all the contacts associated with them, how?

Tags: account, contact

I'm putting together a document for migration purposes and have a list of companies/accounts, I need to get all the contacts associated with these accounts but I am not sure how to proceed. Please can you advise?

Just an edit - I cannot download all contacts and vlookup on Excel as we have over 2million contacts so Excel will not open them all.

I need to report on: contacts with accounts that have opportunities owned by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just go to the Reports tab, create a new report using the Accounts & Contacts data type, add filters to select the companies you're interested in exporting, add the fields from accounts and contact that you want to export, and then run and export the report in CSV format. This report will have one line per contact, which means that the same account will appear on multiple rows if they have multiple contacts. The output might look like this:

```
Account Name, Contact Name, Email
Acme, John Doe, jdoe@acme.example
Acme, Jane Smith, jsmith@acme.example
Contoso, William Black, wblack@contoso.example
```

As a side note, if the account has no contacts, it won't appear in the report. If you need those accounts as well, you'll have to build a [custom report type](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_defining_report_types.htm). Basically, you'd specify that you want "Accounts with and without Contacts," but once the report type is configured, it would operate in a similar manner as described above, except using the custom report type instead of the built-in Accounts & Contacts report type.

Comment: Sorry I think I need to be more specific maybe so I have a list of account names: B&D Manufacturing
Mpp Energy, Llc
NATIONAL BANK FINANCIAL INC
Pls logistics
Global Hydration Water Treatment Systems Inc.
H&E Equipment Services, Inc.
for example but over 1k of them. I need to get all the contacts associated to each account.

Comment: I need to report on: contacts with accounts that have opportunities owned by

Comment: @PaulRogers You should probably modify your question to reflect that intent. I suspect there is a way to get your data, but your question doesn't generally indicate that.

Comment: You could add a custom checkbox to Account just for the purpose of this task. Then prepare your list of Account names as a two column CSV where the second CSV is TRUE for all records. Now run that through the Import Data Wizard for Accounts, update only, match on Account Name, and map the boolean column to your custom checkbox. Any matched records will now have this checked off. Any names that don't match will be listed in the error CSV it e-mails back to you, and you can manually handle the rejects.

Comment: Then you can do a report that filters on Accounts that have this box checked off.